# Working with JQuery to change CSS properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the Jquery UI tabs, and want to change the properties of an element on mouseover.

My HTML is this:

`<ul id="sub-tabs">
      <li><a href="#000"><span>000<br /><p id="ct1">General</p></span></a></li>
</ul>...`

And jquery is:

```
$('#guide-nav ul#sub-tabs span').mouseover(function() {
   $("#guide-nav ul#sub-tabs li p").css("display", "none"); 
});
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul id="sub-tabs">
    <li><a href="#000"><span>000<br /><p id="ct1">General</p></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery is:

```
$('#guide-nav ul#sub-tabs span').mouseover(function() {
   $("#guide-nav ul#sub-tabs li a span p").css("display", "none"); 
});
```

Or try this:

```
$('#guide-nav ul#sub-tabs span').mouseover(function() {
   $("p#ct1").css("display", "none"); 
});
```

Or this:

```
$('#guide-nav ul#sub-tabs span').mouseover(function() {
   $(this).find('p').css("display", "none"); 
});
```

Comment: This did not seem to work either. I was thinking that maybe the Jquery UI Tabs may be rewriting the styles and/or names of the elements, so I removed the call, and still no go.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('#guide-nav ul#sub-tabs span').mouseover(function() {
   $("#guide-nav ul#sub-tabs li p").css({display:"none"}); 
});
```

Comment: That is just another way to write .css("display","none") and would not change anything about how his code reacts.

Comment: Still no go. I may try in a independentenvironment, to see if some other code on the page is messing with it...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i wrapped this in a function and it works...

```
$(function() {                                             
    $('#guide-nav ul#sub-tabs li a span').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).find('p').css("display", "none"); 
    });
});
```

I decided to use the above statement to only hide the elements within the selected tab, because there will be multiples

Answer (score 0):

When I try your code it actually works. Are you sure that the DOM has finished loading when you are executing the javascript?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#guide-nav ul#sub-tabs span').mouseover(function() {
    ("#guide-nav ul#sub-tabs li p").css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

Instead of `.css("display", "none");` you can also use `.hide()`